# coordinatecaptureplugin.dll broken when install plugin offline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Due to unknown reason, I cannot connect to official plugin service in these days.
Alternatively, I downloaded the zip file of QuickMapService and unziped it to the directory

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\python\plugins
```

My QGIS version is 2.18.3
and I have enabled the plugin in the plugin manager.

However, the manager show me the error message like

```
Coordinate Capture

Capture mouse coordinates in different CRS




Category: Vector 

Installed version: Version 0.1 (in C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/plugins/coordinatecaptureplugin.dll)
```

I'm not sure it's due to the plugin itself (unlikely!) or the way I install the plugin (wrong directory?). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

External plugins should be installed to

```
C:\Users\<yourusername>\.qgis2\python\plugins
```

If you want to install QuickMapServices manually, you have to extract it to the folder given above, not under the `C:\Program Files\` folder. The folder you used is for **core** **python** plugins.